# How ORDER BY works in my sql when the data is same?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

When the data having same date( even the micro second ) like below table.
If I There is a table below

| Create_At | User_ID | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-29 09h:09:01.761335 | 4 | 200300 |
| 2022-09-30 12h:09:47.405520 | 6 | 58111 |
| 2022-09-30 12h:09:47.405520 | 6 | 53861 |
| 2022-09-29 11h:09:46.276274 | 6 | 79011 |

I would like to get the latest record per user ID.

When I try to sort the Create_At column by descending order as follow,

```
SELECT * FROM Balance_Table ORDER BY Create_AT Desc;
```

What is the logic behind this sorting?

Comment: Are these the only columns in your table? if so I would say that the design is wrong (there is no primary key, and you actually want the order of events, but the resolution (smallest time unit) of Create_At is not sufficient to distinguish between certain records and you don't have a sequence column. How can you tell which one is latest? as you can't tell neither can the computer!. ORDER BY will bring one or the other depending on how it executes internally, which can change even each time you run the query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I agree with your mention of the design problem, but I would like to know the sorting logic in general. I found the answer in your response. I understand that I should not use SORT BY command in this case!

Comment: Which one is the latest? You have to decide the rules when there's a tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is just sorting the entire *table* on the created at time.  You *could* use the following `LIMIT` query to find the single most recent record:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Balance_Table ORDER BY Create_AT DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But, this would just return a single user's records.  Instead, what you want to be using here on MySQL 8+ is `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Create_AT DESC) rn
    FROM Balance_Table
)

SELECT Create_At, User_ID, Balance
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Given that some users have more than one record as tied for the latest, it might make more sense to use `RANK()`, instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`, and report all ties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Now I find the solution to distinguish the latest record in the database.

Comment: It must be noted that this query would also suffer from the same ambiguity: as to which row of user:6 will get rn=1? Both rows have the same Create_At, therefore either of them can get it; and it is not guaranteed which one. In fact, a different one may be selected when the query is run at different times.

Comment: @tinazmu You're right, and in that case the OP should specify logic for choosing just one record, or else `RANK()` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC
Above query ordering the data only by the score. If you want to order the data by another field as you mentioned, you have the add that field also to the query as below. You have mentions that you want to order by name in acceding order (C > D >E). So I used ORDER BY ASC. Below query will give you the output that you requested.

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC